# Is it possible to make confidential issues in a public git repository?

Tags: github, private, confidential

I would like to keep both public and private issues in my team's github repo.
I'd rather prefer that some issues are not open to other people than just my teamates.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot. [GitHub (still) does not support Confidential Issues](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1958/report-a-security-issue-to-a-project-hosted-at-github). This is a major problem for open-source projects that want to track security bugs using GitHub Issues or record bug notes that contain PII.

[GitLab, however, does](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/issues/confidential_issues.html).

My recommendation is to use create a public issue in your GitHub repo but with an arbitrary or disguised title and description and add tags/metadata that reference the same confidential issue in a non-public store, such as a hosted Bugzilla - you could set-up two-way integration between the two too, using their webhooks and events systems.

Answer (score 4):

The new [Security Advisory](https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-security-vulnerabilities/about-github-security-advisories) feature is a neat way to discuss and fix confidential security issues. You can create a confidential Security Advisory draft (in Security tab) to discuss the issue, and elaborate solution within a confidential branch. You can publish the final advisory, if you want, or even assign CVE number.

Comment: Noticed as of today it also shows up under issue templates if you have those enabled.

Comment: Just to add a note. These private security advisory repositories do NOT run any GH actions workflow. It's planned for Q1 2024.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it goes without saying, but GitHub's official recommendation/workaround suggests creating a second private repo only for private issues: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/creating-and-managing-repositories/creating-an-issues-only-repository

For a single repo having a separate `myrepo_private_issues` repo is a little clunky, but not too bad. At scale it would be a mess. You'd probably want to collect *all* private issues in a single private repo.

I do think it's still preferable to the other answers though.